# JPA delete record on removal from collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project with JPA. I need hibernate to delete a record from the database when it is removed from an entities collection and then a save is called on that entity. Is this possible.
e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLEA")
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "TABLEA_ID")
  private Integer id;
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  @JoinColumn(name="TABLEB_FK", referencedColumnName="TABLEA_ID")
  private List<Child> children; // ??
} 

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLEB")
public class Child {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "TABLEB_ID")
  private Integer id;  
  @Column(name = "TABLEB_FK")
  private Integer fkId;  

}
```

Within this entity class I have a method which sorts out which objects in the collection still exist. In some cases a particular Child object is removed from the collection and a save is called on the Parent entity. Unfortunately I get a ORA-01407: cannot update ("TABLEB"."TABLEB_FK") to NULL.
It seems hibernate updates the relationship to null before it deletes the orphans and the database has a not null constraint on that column. I have all the processing to add/remove the objects within the entity class so cannot explicitly call delete on the individual object and was hoping to cascade this delete from the parent by issuing a save. This may not be possible. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? JPA is an object oriented framework. You should put the Parent in the Child and let JPA take care of the id like it was designed to do. What do you mean you have the processing within the Entity class. Why? What do you mean you can't call delete on the Child, you have a list of them in the Parent?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I thought calling save on the parent where orphan removal is specified would delete any child records no longer in the collection.

Comment: I think so too, but my first concern is that you should have a `@ManyToOne private Parent parent;` in the `Child` class so that JPA understands what's going on. It will only store the id of the Parent as a FK, like you are doing manually, though you will have to have a `mappedBy="parent"` attribute in the `@OneToMany` annotation of the Parent's children property. This tells JPA to use a foreign key instead of a join table.

Comment: Thanks again. This helped me find the solution. I needed to specify parent on child and use mapped by on parent. I think I removed parent from child originally as hibernate seems to do duplicate select of parent when retrieving parent but that is another issue.

Comment: Good stuff, carry on :)